# Looping through multiple variables in view

Tags: python, django

**Views.py**

```
counter = 0
    for house in some model... 
        if house.name = house.selected 
            counter++ 
        else:
            house.correct
```

Assumption: 
correct is a charfield within the house model, looping through multiple houses thus the else condition can be entered multiple times.. so upon completion could most likely will end up with multiple house.corrects

prior to loop any suggestions on the type of variables i could define to store all values i.e. list = [] then when else statement is entered I can do list = house.correct thus at the end I have a list with potentially multiple character values... so this way I can pass the list through to use in context.

is this approach okay or am I doing it poorly ? sorry for the lack of information give hopefully you can understand what I'm getting at. I'm struggling to understand how I can grab all the house.correct values and put them in one data type so i can pass them through context using some variable to see a list of characters.

Answer (score 0):

This can better be implemented using Django ORM:

```
from django.db.models import F

...
incorrect_list = House.objects.exclude(name=F('selected')).values('correct')
```

The [`F` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) here allows you to compare a model field with another field in the same row and the `.values()` method will allow you to return a list with the values of selected columns instead of a queryset.